# ppu-ld cannot find -lspe

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to compile the code below, on CELL BE Simulator(mambo).
//hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <libspe.h>
#include <sched.h>

 extern spe_program_handle_t hello_spu;
 spe_gid_t gid;
 speid_t speids[8];
 int status[8];

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 int i;

printf("Hello World!\n");

gid = spe_create_group (SCHED_OTHER, 0, 1);
if (gid == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed spe_create_group(errno=%d)\n", errno);
    return -1;
}

if (spe_group_max (gid) < 8) {
    fprintf(stderr, "System doesn't have eight working SPEs. I'm leaving.\n");
    return -1;
}

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    speids[i] = spe_create_thread (gid, &hello_spu,NULL, NULL, -1, 0);
    if (speids[i] == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "FAILED: spe_create_thread(num=%d, errno=%d)\n",i, errno);
    exit (3+i);
    }
}

for (i=0; i<8; ++i){
    spe_wait(speids[i], &status[i], 0);
}

__asm__ __volatile__ ("sync" : : : "memory");

return 0;
```

}

//Makefile

```
########################################################################
#           Target
########################################################################

PROGRAM_ppu64   = hello


########################################################################
#           Local Defines
########################################################################

IMPORTS     = ../spu/hello_spu.a -lspe


########################################################################
#           make.footer
########################################################################

include /opt/cell/sdk/buildutils/make.footer
```

After compiling the this, it provides with the following output.

```
$make   
/opt/cell/toolchain/bin/ppu-gcc        -W -Wall -Winline  -I.  -I /opt/cell/sysroot  usr/include -I /opt/cell/sysroot/opt/cell/sdk/usr/include -mabi=altivec -maltivec -O3 -c    

hello.c
hello.c: In function 'main':
hello.c:12: warning: unused parameter 'argc'
hello.c:12: warning: unused parameter 'argv'
/opt/cell/toolchain/bin/ppu-gcc -o hello  hello.o      -L/opt/cell/sysroot/usr/lib64  -L/opt/cell/sysroot/opt/cell/sdk/usr/lib64 -R/opt/cell/sdk/usr/lib64 ../spu/hello_spu.a -lspe
/opt/cell/toolchain/bin/ppu-ld: cannot find -lspe
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

`'ld' cannot find the -lspe library.`The "/opt/cell/sysroot/usr/lib" directory contains following libraries and files,

```
alf,              libblas.so,          libc_stubs.a,       libieee.a,       libnetpbm.so.10,       libnuma.so.1,            libsimdmath.so.3,
crt1.o,           libblas.so.1,        libdl.a,            libm.a,          libnetpbm.so.10.35,    libpthread.a,            libsimdmath.so.3.0.3,
crti.o,           libBrokenLocale.a,   libdl.so,           libmass.a,       libnldbl_nonshared.a,  libpthread_nonshared.a,  libspe2.so,
crtn.o,           libBrokenLocale.so,  libg.a,             libmassv.a,      libnsl.a,              libpthread.so,           libspe2.so.2,
gconv,            libbsd.a,            libgmp.a,           libmcheck.a,     libnsl.so,             libresolv.a,             libspe2.so.2.2.0,
gcrt1.o,          libbsd-compat.a,     libgmp.so,          libmp.a,         libnss_compat.so,      libresolv.so,            libthread_db.so,
libalf.a,         libc.a,              libgmp.so.3,        libmpfr.a,       libnss_dns.so,         librpcsvc.a,             libutil.a,
libalf.so,        libcidn.so,          libgmp.so.3.3.3,    libmp.so,        libnss_files.so,       librt.a,                 libutil.so,
libalf.so.3,      libc_nonshared.a,    libgmpxx.a,         libmp.so.3,      libnss_hesiod.so,      librtkaio.a,             Mcrt1.o,
libalf.so.3.0.0,  libcrypt.a,          libgmpxx.so,        libmp.so.3.1.7,  libnss_nisplus.so,     librt.so,                Scrt1.o,
libanl.a,         libcrypt.so,         libgmpxx.so.3,      libm.so,         libnss_nis.so,         libsimdmath.a,
libanl.so,        libc.so,             libgmpxx.so.3.0.5,  libnetpbm.so,    libnuma.so,            libsimdmath.so
```

How do I link libspe2.so to libspe.so?
Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't link those together. They are different things. You either update your makefile to use `-lspe2` if that's the version of the library you want or you install the version of the library that installs the `libspe.so` library.

Comment: found out libspe.so is deprecated version. Using [-lspe2] worked, but had to change the whole program. Thanx.